# Checkout a dwg file using Vault Api

Tags: c#, winforms, autocad

I am using the following code to checkout a file but it works rarely. It works for a particular file while it doesnt work for some files.

My code is

```
oSettings.DefaultAcquisitionOption = VDF.Vault.Settings.AcquireFilesSettings.AcquisitionOption.Checkout | VDF.Vault.Settings.AcquireFilesSettings.AcquisitionOption.Download;                            
oSettings.LocalPath = fldrpathco;
oSettings.AddEntityToAcquire(oFileIteration);
connection.FileManager.AcquireFiles(oSettings);                            
string p = oSettings.LocalPath.ToString() + oFileIteration.ToString();
```

My requirement is to download the dwg file in the working folder. Can anyone tell me what may be wrong in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example by Wayne Brill:  http://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/2013/06/use-or-with-defaultacquisitionoption-to-download-checkout-with-acquirefiles.html

Code for reference:

```
    private static void downloadFile (VDF.Vault.Currency.Connections.Connection connection, 
        VDF.Vault.Currency.Entities.FileIteration file, string folderPath)
    {
        var settings = new VDF.Vault.Settings.AcquireFilesSettings(connection);
        settings.AddEntityToAcquire(file);
        settings.DefaultAcquisitionOption = VDF.Vault.Settings.AcquireFilesSettings.AcquisitionOption.Checkout |
                                            VDF.Vault.Settings.AcquireFilesSettings.AcquisitionOption.Download;

        settings.LocalPath = new VDF.Currency.FolderPathAbsolute(folderPath);

        connection.FileManager.AcquireFiles(settings);
    }
```